# How to add style or class name and remove other element from web component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-component

I have two components where one is the parent component and the other is the child component. Now the parent has two children within it. which child click for add a style in it, i would require to remove the style in other children. so at a time only one child will keep the style. how to do this?

[LiveDemo](https://jsfiddle.net/fbk6nu59/4/) - **click on the button. I am not able to remove the style back.**

here is my code :

```
class Parent extends HTMLElement {
    shadowRoot;
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
  }

  connectedCallback(){
    this.render();
    }

  render() {
    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `<div>
        <children-holder></children-holder>
      <children-holder></children-holder>
      <children-holder></children-holder>
    </div>`
  }

}

customElements.define('parent-holder', Parent);


class Children extends HTMLElement {
    shadowRoot;
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
  }

  connectedCallback(){
    this.render();
    this.shadowRoot.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
        this.shadowRoot.querySelector('button').style.border = "";
        this.shadowRoot.querySelector('button').style.border = "3px solid red";
    })
    }

  render() {
    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
    <div><button class="button">Click me!</button></div>`
  }

}

customElements.define('children-holder', Children);
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? In live demo, when I clicked the button it gets styled. What button will make it's style remove?

Comment: when you click on a button it should be bordered with red color. other should be removed. so at a time only one button will have the border, which is you clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### a long answer for (eventually) 3 lines of code...

> If you make Custom Element children access a parentNode, and loop its
> DOM elements..
>
> **You are creating a dependency between components**

#### Event Driven solution:

- The click on a button bubbles up the DOM
- so the parent can capture that click event
- The `evt.target` will be the button clicked
- The parent then emits a custom event
- **The Children are listening for that Event, there is NO dependency on the parent**
- Since the Event contains the button clicked,
  each listening element can do its select/unselect code
- And it is less and clearer code

```
class Parent extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
      .attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
      .shadowRoot.innerHTML = `<div>` +
         `<children-holder></children-holder>`.repeat(3) +
         `</div>`
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this.shadowRoot.addEventListener('click', evt => {
      if (evt.target.nodeName === 'CHILDREN-HOLDER')
        document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('myStateEvent', {
          detail: evt.target // THE BUTTON CLICKED
        }));
    });
  }
}

customElements.define('parent-holder', Parent);

class Children extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `<div><button class="button">Click me!</button></div>`;
    document.addEventListener('myStateEvent', evt => {
      let IwasClicked = evt.detail === this;
      this.shadowRoot.querySelector('button').style.border = IwasClicked ? "3px solid red" : ""
    });
  }
}
customElements.define('children-holder', Children);
```

Notes

- dispatch and listen are both on the `document`, you can attach them anywhere
- events bubble UP, not down
- the default events like `click` bubble out of shadow DOM
- Custom Events require `composed:true`
  read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event
- **I did the dispatch in the Parent for clearity**  (A DEPENDENCY!)

It might be better to make the Child do the dispatchEvent,
So it becomes:

*Yo! everyone listening! I was clicked, WE ALL do whatever WE need to do*

And keep all logic in one component:

```
  connectedCallback() {
    let root = this.shadowRoot;
    let eventName = "myStateEvent";
    root.innerHTML = `<div><button class="button">Click me!</button></div>`;
    document.addEventListener(eventName, evt => {
      let button = root.querySelector("button");
      button.style.border = evt.detail === button ? "3px solid red" : "";
    });

    root.addEventListener("click", evt =>
      document.dispatchEvent(
        new CustomEvent(eventName, {
          detail: evt.target // THE BUTTON CLICKED
        })
      )
    );
  }
```

#### Now you understand Event driven solutions

And you might now ask: Why not use the `click` event?

That is possible once you understand that `event.target` is NOT what you might think it is.

**When events originate from shadow DOM, the `event.target` value is the last shadowDOM it pierced**

So your button click sets different `event.target` values:

```
    Listener on <children-holder>   event.target = button
    Listener on <parent-holder>     event.target = <children-holder>
    Listener on document            event.target = <parent-holder>
```

To solve your Button-Select-Color use-case with one `click` event
the button click is the dispatcher, sending a click event UP the DOM,
through all shadowDOM boundaries

You have to check the `event.composedPath()` function which retuns an Array of ALL DOM elements the Event passed.
(note: `event.path` is Chrome only!!)

## So all code required for your style question is:

```
  connectedCallback() {
    let root = this.shadowRoot;
    root.innerHTML = `<div><button>Click me!</button></div>`;
    root.host.getRootNode().addEventListener("click", evt => {
      let button = root.querySelector("button");
      button.style.border = evt.composedPath().includes(button) ? "3px solid red" : "";
    });
  }
```

Notes

- `root.host.getRootNode()` allows one selected button per parent Component
- change to `document` and it is one button per page
- `evt.composedPath().includes(root)` identifies the child-component

#### Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/WebComponents/bc9tw1qa/

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve your desired behavior in a couple of ways, I'll describe 2 of them:

**CSS-only:**
When you click a button, it will receive the CSS `focus` state. So using the css

```
button:focus {
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

Will give only the most recently clicked button a border. The `focus` state will be removed when you click anywhere else on the screen.

**JS solution**
The separate shadow-roots make it a bit hard to traverse all the buttons using JS in an elegant way, but this should do the trick:

```
const button = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const parentShadowRoot = this.shadowRoot.host.getRootNode();
  const childrenHolders = parentShadowRoot.querySelectorAll('children-holder');
  childrenHolders.forEach(holder => {
    const button = holder.shadowRoot.querySelector('button');
    button.style.border = "";
  })
  button.style.border = "3px solid red";
})
```

Comment: Don't traverse (other) components; use Events, see answer below

Answer (score 2):

You could simplify your two classes, check the example snippet.

```js
class Parent extends HTMLElement {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.sroot = this.attachShadow({
      mode: 'open'
    });
    this.render();
  }

  render() {
    this.sroot.innerHTML = `<div>
     <children-holder></children-holder>
      <children-holder></children-holder>
      <children-holder></children-holder>
    </div>`
  }

}

customElements.define('parent-holder', Parent);


class Children extends HTMLElement {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.sroot = this.attachShadow({
      mode: 'open'
    });
    let style = document.createElement("style");
    style.append('button:focus {border: 3px solid red;}');
    this.sroot.append(style);
    this.render();
  }

  render() {
    let button = document.createElement("button");
    button.innerHTML = "Click me!";
    button.classList.add("button");
    let div = document.createElement("div");
    div.append(button);
    this.sroot.append(div);
  }

}

customElements.define('children-holder', Children);
```

```html
<parent-holder></parent-holder>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first retrieve all the button's siblings as well as the button itself then you can remove the border from all of them and finally, add the red border to the button that was clicked.

1. Retrieve the clicked button as well as it's siblings by using `parentNode.children`.
2. You will get an `HTMLCollection` of the buttons on which you can now use **[Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)** to get a new, shallow-copied Array of your HTMLCollection which you can now iterate over.
3. Finally, you can now just remove the border from all the buttons and then add the border to the clicked button.

```
    this.shadowRoot.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {  
        let x = this.parentNode.children;

        Array.from(x).forEach((e) => {
            e.shadowRoot.querySelector('button').style.border = "";
        });

        this.shadowRoot.querySelector('button').style.border = "3px solid red";
    });
```

---

Here is a live example of the above in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/Lrbn7d8t/18/